# Combining two/several charting controls in one in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-charts, charts

Can anyone please tell how to combine two controls, not necessary charting controls, at one? What I need to do? Maybe there is a book or example?

I'm using `System.DataVisualization.Charting` controls. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean combine two controls into one? Do you want to always have the same two side by side? Or do you want two types of charts in the same charting space?

Comment: The second one. Got any practicalsuggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of combining controls is really about aggregating functionality.

The functionality which may span multiple controls can be aggregated in two ways; either via a `UserControl` which simply encapsulates the controls as they exist in their original form or creating a custom control which will provide the functionality from the varying controls which you are after.

The [differences between a `UserControl` and custom control](http://wpftutorial.net/CustomVsUserControl.html) are subtle on the surface but significant underneath the covers. Depending on your technology; WinForms, WPF, etc... there are samples online on for [creating a `UserControl`](http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=creating%20usercontrol).